# Using meta_query with custom query vars leads to 404 on pagination with Timber

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I have a CPT that I'm filtering with custom query vars associated with ACF fields. Pagination pages lead to 404 whenever the meta_query is active. Any assistance would be appreciated.

On `search.php`

```
if ( $post_type == 'funded_grants' ) {

  $program_type = get_query_var('program_type');
  $contributor = get_query_var('contributor');
  $researchers = get_query_var('researchers');
  $area_of_research = get_query_var('area_of_research');
  $disease_areas = get_query_var('disease_areas');
  $province = get_query_var('province');
  $start_date = get_query_var('start_date');
  $end_date = get_query_var('end_date');

  $meta_query = bc_create_meta_query();

  $args = [
    's' => $text_query,
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
  ];

  $context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery($args);

  Timber::render(['archive-funded_grants.twig'], $context);

}
```

`In functions.php`

```
function filterFundedGrantsSearch($query) {
    if ($query->is_search && $query->get('post_type') == 'funded_grants' && !is_admin() ) {
      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
      $query->set( 'paged', (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 );
    }
    return $query;
  }

  add_filter('pre_get_posts','filterFundedGrantsSearch');
```

I've tried every possible solution I can find in the docs.

Comment: What is this `bc_create_meta_query()`? The `meta_query` expects an array of arrays.

Comment: This is also in functions.php but unfortunately I can't post it because it's too long. But the meta query works as expected.

Comment: have you tried using `'paged' => $paged,`?